# Is this an equivalent norm on $H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset  \mathbb{R}^2$ be a sufficiently nice domain. It is known that the norm on the space $H^2(\Omega)$ is given by $$||f||^2_2 = ||f||^2_{L^2} + ||\nabla f||^2_{L^2} + ||\Delta f||^2_{L^2}$$
I also know that there is an equivalent norm on  $H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ given by
$$||f||^2_2 =||\Delta f||^2_{L^2}$$

My question is what about the norm
$$|f|^2_2 = ||\nabla f||^2_{L^2} + ||\Delta f||^2_{L^2}$$

**Attempt:** Yes, it is equivalent. It is obvious that
$$||f||^2_2 = ||f||^2_{L^2} + ||\nabla f||^2_{L^2} + ||\Delta f||^2_{L^2} \geq  ||\nabla f||^2_{L^2} + ||\Delta f||^2_{L^2} = |f|^2_2. $$
On the other hand, since we are in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ we can use Poincare inequality with constant $C_p$ and write
$$||f||^2_2 = ||f||^2_{L^2} + ||\nabla f||^2_{L^2} + ||\Delta f||^2_{L^2} \leq (1+ C^2_p) ||\nabla f||^2_{L^2} + ||\Delta f||^2_{L^2}$$
Therefore, for some contact $C$ we can have $$||f||^2_2 \leq C |f|^2_2 .$$

From both inequalities we deduce that $||f||^2_2$ and $|f|^2_2$ are equivalent on $H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. You use two different norms $\|\cdot \|_2$. Also $H^2 \cap H^1 = H^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated.

Comment: On your last line, it should be $H^2 \cap H_0^1$ instead of $H^2 \cap H^1$.

Comment: @grew You are right! I changed it. Thank you.